# Understanding MySQL licensing

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to figure out if I require a MySQL commercial license. After reading from their site, it was still confusing to me. I have a phone call set up with them tomorrow, but I want the community's knowledge as well.

I'm creating an [ERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning) desktop application for my company. We will probably end up using the .NET framework to produce it since we are all using Windows machines. This software will be used internally with up to 50 users (13 right now).

If I were to open source the project (put it on GitHub), can I use the free version of MySQL?

If not, we probably would just stick to our original plan and purchase SQL Server (US$8,000, ouch) since it appears the commercial license for MySQL is US$5,000.

I don't have any experience with PostgreSQL. Would you recommend that or another database that are completely free to use, and able to work in a production environment?

Comment: The first part of this question will be answered for you by a rep in less than a day and the 2nd part is off topic. There is also extensive online content on pricing models if you google it.

Comment: If you want open source with no strings attached, use Postgres, not MySQL. It's superior in most other aspects, too.

Comment: It doesn't help to tag a bunch of unrelated products.

Comment: @SMor Every tag that I mentioned is mentioned in the question which is why I did it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's what I understand:

- If you distribute MySQL with a non-open-source project, you would
  need to pay for the commercial license.
- If you want Oracle support for MySQL, you would need to pay for the
  commercial license.
- If you want to use some MySQL tools that are licensed only to Oracle
  support customers, such as the MySQL Enterprise Monitor, Enterprise
  backup, various plugins, etc. then you would need to get an Oracle
  support contract, and that requires you to pay for commercial
  licenses.
- If you want to modify MySQL source code and distribute your
  modifications as a non-open-source offering, you would need to pay
  for the commercial license.

Note that you can still charge money for open-source modifications. This has nothing to do with being *gratis*. It has to do with whether you offer your modifications under a GPL-compatible license, which would allow your customers to further modify and redistribute.

In most other cases, you can use the Community Edition. For example:

- You can install MySQL Community Edition at your site and use it, or even modify it, whether your product is open-source or not. Also whether you charge for your product or not.
- You can make and distribute a non-open-source product that uses MySQL, as long as you don't *distribute* MySQL Community Edition with it. You would require your customers install MySQL themselves. They could then use your product to connect to the instance of MySQL Community Edition that they installed.

- You can distribute your product and include MySQL Community Edition with it, if you offer your product under a [GPL-compatible license](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html).

I do know at least one business that switched from MySQL to [PostgreSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) specifically because they wanted to distribute the RDBMS software with their non-open-source product. PostgreSQL uses a non-viral [open-source license](https://www.postgresql.org/about/licence/) similar to [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses) or [MIT licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License).

*The usual disclaimers apply: I'm not a lawyer and this is not legal advice; I do not claim that the above is accurate; don't make any business decisions based on stuff you read from strangers on the internet, including me.*

See also:

- *[When Are You Required to Have a Commercial MySQL License?](https://web.archive.org/web/20201109020025/https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/02/17/when-are-you-required-to-have-a-commercial-mysql-license/)* (2009)
- *[Frequently Asked Questions about the GNU Licenses](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html)*